# Unreliable system audio

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, audio, monterey

I often have stutters when playing audio. It happens sometimes with Bluetooth headphones, but more often and more consistently with a built-in speaker and 3.5mm headphone jack output. This is a comparison between the original audio played in Music.app (this also happens with other apps) and the recorded system audio (recorded using Audio Hijack, confirmed identical with the recording made by an external ADC recorder). There is noticeable stutter coming from certain sections being repeated and certain sections being "deleted" or "muted"

Original audio:
[image]

Recorded audio:
[image]

The recordings are available [here](https://github.com/sclsj/macos-audio-problem).

What might cause this kind of problem? How should I troubleshoot it?